# Is there a way to restrict users from entering characters beyond a certain limit in oracle jet

Tags: oracle-jet

Is there a way to restrict users from entering characters beyond a certain limit in oracle jet? The maxlength attribute of input html element doesn't let users enter beyond the maxlength characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit based on comments:*

Unfortunately OJET does not provide a way to do that. It could be done through jQuery like this:

**HTML**

```
<oj-input-text id="text-input" value="{{value}}"></oj-input-text>
```

**JS**

```
this.value = ko.observable("Green");
self.bindingsApplied = function(){
    $($('#text-input').find('input')[0]).attr('maxlength','5');
};
```

`bindingsApplied` is a method implicitly called by OJET after the viewModel binds with the HTML. It is similar to `$(document).ready();`

---

*Original answer:*

Yes there is. Not only can you limit the number of characters allowed, you can provide custom error messages as well - or let OJET display the default - when you don't meet the requirements.

HTML:

```
<oj-input-text value="{{value}}"
              validators="[[validators]]"
              placeholder="up to 10 characters">
</oj-input-text>
```

JS:

```
self.validators = ko.computed(function()
{
  return [{
    type: 'length', 
    options: {max: 10,
              messageSummary : {
        tooLong: 'Too Long: Too many characters'
      }}}];
});
```

More examples [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jetCookbook.html?component=validators&demo=lengthValidator).

Comment: Thanks Ray .. But my problem is different.. **i have to restrict users from entering characters beyond a certain limit**.  user should not able to enter in that field if exceeded given max length.. Its basic feature of HTML Check this Example link [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_maxlength).

Comment: provided example allowing user to enter more than 10 character

Answer (score 0):

If you are using general input holders, you lose many OJET functionalities. To achieve the same with OJET specified component, I think this is what you should go for -

I have implemented input box where it accepts input exactly 8 characters & you can have any other custom validations -

HTML (input element)

```
<oj-input-text  data-bind="event:{keyup: sortCodeEventUp }"
            type="text"
            :id="sortCode"
            name="sortCode"
            raw-value="{{sortCodeRawValue}}"
            value="{{sortCode}}"
            validators="{{[sortCodeValidator]}}"
            required>
</oj-input-text>
```

JS

```
self.sortCodeRawValue = ko.observable();
var sortCodePrevValue = "";

self.sortCodeValidator = {
    validate: function (value) {
        if (value.length !== 8) {
            throw new Error("You must enter 8 charecters");
        }
    }
};

self.sortCodeEventUp = function () {
    if (self.sortCodeRawValue().length <= 8) {
        sortCodePrevValue = self.sortCodeRawValue();
    } else {
        $("#sortCode").val("");
        $("#sortCode").val(sortCodePrevValue);
    }
};
```

**BEHAVIOR**
after you input 8 characters, 9th character when you press, it automatically gets deleted (which serves the purpose of restricting user from entering more characters than limitation)